# HTML Pages appear differently between browsers bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im experiencing different layout in Chrome, IE and FireFox on my bootstrap project.

I suspect it has something to do with the imports.

header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MY WEB</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('thetime').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
    }
    </script>


    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    <style>
        /* Icon when the collapsible content is shown */
        .btn:after {
            font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
            content: "\e114";
            float: right;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }
        /* Icon when the collapsible content is hidden */
        .btn.collapsed:after {
            content: "\e080";
        }
    </style>

</head>
```

Bottom of the html page:

```
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body></html>
```

Most of the my styling is written inside the html page.

Some of the objects that appear differently (Screenshots are added in the End):

1. Search form (also - how can I get rid of the arrow and leave only the search glyphicon?)
2. Button

Show

3. Navbar

Screenshots of the differences:

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]
Firefox: 
[image]

IE: 
[image]

Comment: Please add a working Snippet

Comment: It is because all the browsers do no accept all the css. This is where you should be using vendor prefixing. I would suggest you to inspect the element in Firefox and check which line of CSS is causing the issue and replace with a generic css which is accepted across all the browsers or use vendor prefixes.

Comment: Vishnu which snippet do you mean ? And i've tried to inspect but didn't find the answer there... the reason is my usage of the navigation bar, it makes the redundant arrows as well, but I don't know what to do with it

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in FF elements inside your buttons are centered. Make sure that you have covered such things. You can always use [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com)